# AWS Cloud9...great but I can only start it from the root account in the default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I've tried using Cloud9 in my root account with the default VPC and this works great. I love it. However, that's not very secure.

When I tried simulating a more realistic scenario--logging in as an IAM user with Cloud9administrators policy applied, it seemed to allow me to create a C9 environment, but the instance never seemed to actually get going. It just timed out with the message

> "This is taking longer than expected. If you think there might be an
>   issue, contact AWS Support. It might be caused by VPC configuration
>   issues. Please check documentation."

This is pretty much a show stopper. Is there any way around it? I've also tried using a bigger instance size--small, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

I also noticed that I seem to get similar errors if I create a C9 environment in another VPC (public subnet, so it should be all good but it's not).

I've tried different configurations for this:

- In a new VPC (with settings to match)
- Default VPC
- Different regions: Oregon and North VA (2 big regions which support C9)

My conclusion from this is that it seems to take a long time to spin up even in different environments. It would be helpful if I could get 'gold settings' that are confirmed to work in all situations. In the meantime, I'm planning to test EC2 instance configurations.

Comment: Have you checked that your VPC meets all the requirements specified here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/vpc-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case 
When I Changed The Browser (e.g. Safari TO Chrome)
The Message (This is taking ...) clearly disappeared .
I don't have any idea about the reason why Browser_exchange works.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself in a similar position.

Turns out I didn't have an internet gateway attached to the VPC. Further more, the route table associated with the VPC needed a new route for 0.0.0.0/0 that used this gateway.

This finally solved the connection issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but the answer turned out to be quite simple actually: AWS doesn't support the default C9 instance type in all its AZs (and doesn't let you know this when you create an environment). If you are unlucky enough to setup your network in an AZ which doesn't support the C9 instance you choose, even if it's the default type, then everything looks OK, but when you try to spin up your C9 environment it will mysteriously error out with little feedback to the user (except for an occasional sad trombone sound effect playing faintly in the background). The answer is to verify that the AZ you choose for your network supports the instance type you select for C9.